# how to get multiple rows from one row in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe in spark like below and I want to convert all the column in different rows with respect to first column id.

```
+----------------------------------+
| id code1 code2 code3 code4 code5 |
+----------------------------------+
| 1 A B C D E                      |
| 1 M N O P Q                      |
| 1 P Q R S T                      |
| 2 P A C D F                      |
| 2 S D F R G                      |
+----------------------------------+
```

I want the output like below format

```
+-------------+
|     id code |
+-------------+
|     1 A     |
|     1 B     |
|     1 C     |
|     1 D     |
|     1 E     |
|     1 M     |
|     1 N     |
|     1 O     |
|     1 P     |
|     1 Q     |
|     1 P     |
|     1 Q     |
|     1 R     |
|     1 S     |
|     1 T     |
|     2 P     |
|     2 A     |
|     2 C     |
|     2 D     |
|     2 F     |
|     2 S     |
|     2 D     |
|     2 F     |
|     2 R     |
|     2 G     |
+-------------+
```

Can anyone please help me here how I will get the above output with spark and scala.

Comment: No its not duplicate of above question which you mentioned

Comment: This question is not related to json format

Answer (score 2):

using [array](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#array(org.apache.spark.sql.Column...)), [explode](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#explode(org.apache.spark.sql.Column)) and `drop` functions should have you the desired output as

```
df.withColumn("code", explode(array("code1", "code2", "code3", "code4", "code5")))
    .drop("code1", "code2", "code3", "code4", "code5")
```

OR

as defined by *undefined_variable*, you can just use `select`

```
df.select($"id", explode(array("code1", "code2", "code3", "code4", "code5")).as("code"))
```

Comment: Thanks @ramesh its working as expected for me.. This is something which I was looking for :)

Comment: Thanks @DivasNikhra, please accept and upvote if the answer helped

Answer (score 1):

```
df.select(col("id"),explode(concat_ws(",",Seq(col(code1),col("code2"),col("code3"),col("code4"),col("code5")))))
```

Basically idea is first `concat` all required columns and then `explode` it